# Error with County_Choropleth in R When Creating Map

Tags: r, choropleth

I'm having an issue running the `county_choropleth` map generating function. My data set is basically two data frames that I used `cbind` to bind together.  The first data set was from `county.regions` (so I got the data formatting right for `county_choropleth`) and the second one contained my data, and the two are sorted exactly by counties in New York.

Here's a link to a snapshot of the data frame:

[image: Image of Dataframe]

As guided by the R instructions, I've named the relevant columns that I want to be the data to be shown on the map as "value" and then put in the following code to create the map:

```
county_choropleth(big_data, state_zoom = "new york")
```

This throws the following error:

> Error: length(unique(na.omit(choropleth.df$value))) <= 9 is not TRUE

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Haven't been able to find a good explanation of what it's trying to say with the error.    Thanks!

Comment: pictures aren't code/data. please make the effort to `dput()` the data in the future.

Answer (score 1):

---

Value column in your df has to be numeric. Otherwise it's assumed that it's a character or factor and the routine quits if the # of unique values in the column is greater than 9.

https://github.com/trulia/choroplethr/blob/master/R/usa.R

```
 render_helper = function(choropleth.df, scale_name, theme)
{
  # maps with numeric values are mapped with a continuous scale
  if (is.numeric(choropleth.df$value))
  {
    ggplot(choropleth.df, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
      geom_polygon(aes(fill = value), color = "dark grey", size = 0.2) + 
      self$get_scale() + 
      theme;
  } else { # assume character or factor
    stopifnot(length(unique(na.omit(choropleth.df$value))) <= 9) # brewer scale only goes up to 9

    ggplot(choropleth.df, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
      geom_polygon(aes(fill = value), color = "dark grey", size = 0.2) + 
      self$get_scale() + 
      theme;
  }
},
```

Comment: To add to this answer, you can convert the value column to numeric by `big_data$value <- as.numeric (gsub (",", "", big_data$value))` which will remove the commas